# How the first Datatable row can be clicked automatically without user interaction?

Tags: javascript, datatables

[image]

*select is a radio button that comes only when status is completed.
I want when this table data is populated then first-row should be preselected
and should be clicked own without the user intervention.*

```
  if (row.status != null && row.status.length > 0 && 
 (row.status[len].status == "InProgress" || row.status[len].status == "NotStarted")) {
 return "<td><input type='radio' id='clickview' name='viewStatus' title='Select' 
 class='clickview clickviewcompleted'  ></td>";
 }
```

On click on first-row select radio button, want to do some activity.
This is my Datatable

```
<div id="multitable" class="x_title">
                  <h2>Table Details</h2>
                  <ul class="nav navbar-right panel_toolbox">
                   <li><a class="clickrefresh"><i class="fa fa-refresh"></i></a>
                    </li>
                    <li><a class="collapse-link"><i class="fa fa-angle-up shftup"></i></a>
                    </li>

                  </ul>

                  <div class="clearfix"></div>
               <!--  </div> -->
                <div class="x_content">
                  <div style="width:100%;">
                  <table id="multisatustable" class="table  table-striped table-bordered" style="width:100%;" >
                </table>

                 </div>

                </div>
              </div>
```

There is no solution available for this.

Comment: `var table = $('#myTable').DataTable();
 
table.row(':eq(0)', { page: 'current' }).select();` try this.

Comment: I have already tried this does not work for me.  table.row(...).select is not a function was getting the error. tried by api as well did not work for me.

Comment: add this after table renders